# Why is PHP's so called "built" in mail function not working?

Tags: php, email

So I am pretty new to PHP and I want to create an email confirmation page using PHP (I use [repl.it](https://repl.it)). So I search up ways to send an email using PHP but all the sites I looked into said to use the "built in" `mail()` function. But when I look at other similar StackOverflow questions, they say you have to import it or something. If the `mail` function is built in, then why do you have to import it? I do as they say but it still returned an error:

```
sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found
[Wed Jan 15 01:43:57 2020] thisIsWhereMyIpAddressWas [200]: /
```

> Note that I censored my IP address.

So back to the question, why isn't the mail function working? Here is my code:

```php
//mail info
$to = 'example@email.com';
$subj = 'Test Subject';
$msg = 'This was an email sent with PHP';
$headers = 'From: noreply@dontreply.com';

//send email
mail($to_email,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

I looked all over the web to find an answer including StackOverflow but there doesn't seem to be a good answer. Maybe it is depreciated or it never existed at all? Someone please help!

Comment: Looks like `sendmail` is not installed on your server. Have you tried `sudo install apt-get sendmail` ? Are you using XAMPP or something similar?

Comment: i use repl.it, it hosts php web servers.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding these to the php.ini file?

```
SMTP = smtp.example.com
smtp_port = 25
username = info@example.com
password = yourmailpassord
sendmail_from = info@example.com
```

However I strongly suggest you to not use the built in mailer on PHP, check [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) instead.

Comment: I use (repl.it)[repl.it] so there isn't a `php.ini` file

Comment: @MrPizzaGuy I don't think repl.it allow you to send emails through its editor. Many things are restricted on repl.it and online compilers due to safety reasons.

Comment: yes but I tried it with many other PHP compilers and it also didn't work.